# Entity Framework transaction managment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, transactions

Is it possible manually manage entityframework transactions.

I'm developing ASP.NET MVC application and I want to use custom ActionFilterAttribute, which will open transaction before execute controller action code and commit transaction after view rendered if no error occured. Something like TransactionAttribute in SharpArchitecture.

I want use sql transactions, not system transaction scope.

Comment: Maybe this helps? Just skipped over the example, don't know if this matches your expectations:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/bb738523(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: thanks, but linked page describes solution with using System.Transactions.TransactionScope

Comment: Why don't you want to use TransactionScope?

Comment: I'm afraid that using TransactionScope can give me performance issues and also in business logic layer i have some logging operations which should executes in some other independent transaction...

Comment: SaveChanges always creates a transaction if no ambient transaction is present so I wonder why it is not enough?

Comment: @Pawel if I will call SaveChanges in OnResultExecuted method of my custom ActionFilterAttribute, is it be right solution?

Comment: @Yusupov To be honest I think it is a bad solution, but that is just my opinion.

Comment: @Yusupov - I don't really know since I don't understand your architecture. I am just saying that SaveChanges always creates a transaction to avoid random partial updates if something goes wrong.

Comment: I want to implement something like https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture/blob/master/Solutions/SharpArch.NHibernate/Web/Mvc/TransactionAttribute.cs. SharpArchtecture uses NHibernate, I want to implement this behavior by using EF. I am developing application using EF 4.3 Code First